# Unable to set 'data' attribute for 'Object' tag in jQuery. [IE8 only]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am creating an object element dynamically in jQuery, to render some content. It works in all browsers except IE8.

The code:

```
    j$(document).ready(function(){ 
        j$('.objContainer').html(j$('<object>').attr(
                            {'data':'http://www.stackoverflow.com',
                             'type':'text/html'}));
    });
```

The HTML structure created after the execution(in IE8):

```
    <object type="text/html"></object>
```

In other browsers[IE9, Firefox, Chrome]:

```
    <object data="http://www.stackoverflow.com" type="text/html"></object>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: I suspect this is due to same-origin policy restrictions in IE8. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535859(v=vs.85).aspx): *In IE9 Standards mode, the object element is allowed to load content from other domains. In IE8 Standards mode, however, this is not allowed.*

Comment: Just a guess, but could it have something to do with stackoverflow.com using X-Frame-Options to prevent embedding, and IE reacting to that weirdly? Try embedding http://example.iana.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me: using the IE8 developer tools, I can see the data attribute. Here's a [screenshot](http://static.inky.ws/image/3892/5-3-2013%203-30-02%20PM.png).

*(I know I shouldn't have to say it, but: you need to make sure that you're allowing scripts to run.)*

Comment: You were right. There was silly spelling mistake in actual code. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

as you see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), data (**dataset**) is not supported by *IE*.

What you can do is *rename* **data** to **data-foo** and `then $(..).data("foo")` will work
even in **IE** because of a special handling by jquery itself.

This is a way to bypass *dataset* limitation for **IE**.

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine, Though i recommend you use $.data() method

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

It is much safer, and jQuery ensures that the data is removed when DOM elements are removed via jQuery methods.

Example:

```
<object id='myObj' data-url="http://www.stackoverflow.com" type="text/html"></object>
```

And you can read the value like:

```
var url = $('#myObj').data('url');// Read the value
$('#myObj').data('url', 'some-other-value');// Set a new value
```

Comment: `.data()` doesn't place the information in the DOM (i.e., it doesn't set the `data` attribute).